# Estimate the probability of a fair die given the distribution of rolls

Tags: probability, estimation

Suppose I roll a die 142 times and get the following distribution {1: 0.134, 2: 0.197, 3: 0.169, 4: 0.183, 5: 0.162, 6: 0.155}, how do I estimate if it is a fair die (i.e., what's the probability that the die is fair)?

I don't need an exact solution but what mathematical tools can I use to solve this problem?

Edit: you can assume the rolls are iid.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: You can perform a hypothesis test that the die is fair using e.g. a [Pearson's chi-squared test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson's_chi-squared_test) for goodness of fit; note this is not the same thing as "the probability that the die is fair".

Comment: @Adam Hypothesis test is useful but I want a direct probability, are there any tools/methods in mathematics that can do it?

Comment: You can do a Bayesian test, but that can give completely different answers depending on how you choose your prior. There's no such thing as "the" probability. @johnc

Comment: @Adam What if I model the rolling of the die as a categorical distribution with 5 parameters and do a maximum likelihood estimation to find out these parameters? Would that give "the" probability?

Comment: No, that process doesn't give you a probability that the die is fair. It's halfway to a hypothesis test, which is something different, as above. @johnc

Answer (score 1):

There is no way of calculating the probability of a fair die given the distribution of rolls. However, a hypothesis test can be performed to accept/reject that the die is fair, which is a classical example of Pearson's chi-squared test.

Credits to Adam. See details in the comment section.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It's not that there's no way of **calculating** "the" probability. The definite article still seems to imply that there is such a thing, independent of your prior. As Adam correctly explained in the comments, there isn't. A correct formulation would be "Without assuming a prior, there is no such thing as the probability of the die being fair, and hence there is no way of calculating such a probability".